# Run user script only if page has a password field

Tags: javascript, if-statement, userscripts

I have a short piece of JavaScript code that I'm using as a user script. The action works fine, but I want to add if-statement to it and don't know how to structure it.

In plain language, I want it to do this:

- If there is a password input field on the page, then do not run my action.

or alternately

- If there is no password input field on this page, then run my action.

How is this accomplished? I'm fiddling with `document.querySelectorAll` but so far no luck.

Comment: If either of the answers below helped solve your issue, then you should mark the one that best helped you as correct. This will help guide others with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to check for the existence.

```js
if (!document.querySelector('input[type=password]')) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: As a newbie, the `//your code here` comment truly helped! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this query with `document.querySelector()`: `input[type="password"]`. If you don't get a result, it will return `null` and you know it doesn't exist on the page.

You can then use this to end the userscript by returning.

Here's two examples (same JS, first has a password, second doesn't):

```js
(function(){
  if (document.querySelector('input[type="password"]') !== null) {
    return;
  }
  console.log('userscript');
})();
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="password">
```

```js
(function(){
  if (document.querySelector('input[type="password"]') !== null) {
    return;
  }
  console.log('userscript');
})();
```

```html
<input type="text">
```